# Borders on dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, border

I want a border around the pdf content.

```vb
Sub BorderFormat()
Dim myrange As String
Dim myrange2 As String

myrange = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Address
myrange2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & myrange).BorderAround (ColorIndex = 33), (Weight = xlThick)
' To add border, still not working!

End Sub
```

On `Range("A1:" & myrange).BorderAround (ColorIndex = 33), (Weight = xlThick)`

but I get this error:

> run time error 1004 - BorderAround method of Range class failed.

Comment: Why have it outside the `with`?

Comment: Cause I am an idiot I think.... But when I put it within the with I get a run time error 1004 - BorderAround method of Range class failed.

Comment: Oh so you don't understand the code you have. The `with` is for `ActiveSheet.PageSetup`, you will need to break it down.

Comment: @findwindow So I need to set up a separate With function? Sorry the with I dont understand well at all.

Comment: `Range("A1:" & myrange).BorderAround ColorIndex: = 33, Weight: = xlThick`

Comment: Yea, `:=` with no `()` or just `,` with `()`. I am surprised compiler didn't bark at it. Also, it's not your lack of understanding of `with` but objects. Coding is all about objects and their methods and properties.

Comment: @findwindow - if you're hanging out here I reckon you are ... `on error resume next`

Comment: @SJR Range("A1:" & myrange).BorderAround ColorIndex: = 33, Weight: = xlThick still gives me that runtime error. 

findwindow are you saying I should adjust to 
With Activesheet
Range("A1:" & myrange).BorderAround ColorIndex: = 33, Weight: = xlThick
end with
??

Comment: @findwindow - then you're an amateur like me, avoiding the day job.

Comment: What is the value of `myrange`?

Comment: No `with`, just `Activesheet.Range("A1:" & myrange).BorderAround ColorIndex: = 33, Weight: = xlThick`

Comment: @SJR i use excel a lot for work so started learning vba to make my job easier.

Comment: @SJR I have the main sub that defines myrange above. It basically is finding the bottom right cell with data in "F". 

Findwindow, even with the activesheet.range it is failing with that same runtime error

Comment: What does `debug.print myrange` say?

Comment: What error do you get? Is the sheet protected?

Comment: @SJR I get  I get a run time error 1004 - BorderAround method of Range class failed.

Comment: I also get this if I try this code:

Sub BorderFormat()
Dim myrange As String


ActiveSheet.Range("a1:" & ActiveSheet.Range("F1"). _
    End(xlDown).Address).Select
' To add border, still not working!
ActiveSelection.BorderAround (ColorIndex = 33), (Weight = xlThick)

End Sub

Select method of range class failed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work this way:

```
Sub BorderFormat()
Dim MyRange as String
MyRange = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Address
Sheets("*MySheetName*").Range(Selection,("A1:" & MyRange)).Select
Activesheet.Range("A1:" & MyRange).BorderAround Colorindex:=33, wight:=xlThick
End Sub
```

Good luck all!